# Determining Linear Fractional Transformations

Tags: geometry

Determine the linear fractional transformation f where $1 \rightarrow 2$, $3 \rightarrow 5$ and $7 \rightarrow 4$.

I figured out how to do two different linear fractional transformations where $1 \rightarrow 2$ and $3 \rightarrow 5$, but I do not know how to do this when there is three.

Comment: You will find your answer here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Explicit_determinant_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $z_1,z_2,z_3$ the starting points $1,3,7$ and $w_1,w_2,w_3$ their images:$2,5,4$, in this order.

The function
$$z\longmapsto \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\cdot\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}$$
is the unique function such that $F(z_1)=0,F(z_2)=\infty,F(z_3)=1$. If $w=F(z)$ is the function such that $F(z_i)=w_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, then $w$ and $z$ are related by the formula
$$\frac{w-w_1}{w-w_2}\cdot\frac{w_3-w_2}{w_3-w_1}=\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\cdot\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}$$

Plugging your data in the formula you get
$$w=\frac{26z-38}{7z-13}$$

Comment: thank you! :) this makes a lot more sense now.